# Finding exponent of a prime in $100!$

Tags: permutations

If $100!=2^m.I$ (Where $"I"$ is multiplication of odd numbers) then find the value of $"m"$

Comment: Forgetting about $I, 2^m  = 2\cdot 4\cdot 6.... \cdot 100 = 2\cdot 50!$. Proceed...

Comment: @trueblueanil, I didn't get your approach.

Answer (score 2):

> In general when you want to find the exponent of a prime $p$ in $n!$, you just need top calculate $$\left[\frac{n}{p}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{p^2}\right]+\cdots + \left[\frac{n}{p^k}\right]$$ where $k$ is the largest positive integer such that $p^k\le n\le p^k+1.$

Note: $[.]$ denotes gretest integer function.

In your case $n=100$ and $p=2$, so you need to evaluate $$\left[\frac{100}{2}\right]+ \left[\frac{100}{2^2}\right] + \left[\frac{100}{2^3}\right]+ \left[\frac{100}{2^4}\right]+\left[\frac{100}{2^5}\right]+\left[\frac{100}{2^6}\right]$$

Comment: explain me complete solution please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

This may help you.